# primefaces remoteCommand action is not getting called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, actionlistener, remotecommand

I have the following code:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="navigateTo" actionListener="#{searchControllerHelper.dummyActionListener}" 
    action="#{searchControllerHelper.navigateTo}" update="searchPanelForm" 
    onstart="plsWaitDlg.show()" onsuccess="plsWaitDlg.hide()"/>
```

Controller Code as under:
Thank you Lars. Code of the bean as under:

```
public String navigateTo() throws FetchException {
    if (null == this.getSelectedMenuLink()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (this.getSelectedMenuLink().longValue() == 1L) {
        this.prevSelectedMenuLink = this.selectedMenuLink;
        this.location = null;
        return searchCRE();
    }
    else if (this.getSelectedMenuLink().longValue() == 2L) {
        this.prevSelectedMenuLink = this.selectedMenuLink;
        this.selectedLoanType=null;
        return searchLoans();
    }
    else if (this.getSelectedMenuLink().longValue() == 3L) {
        this.prevSelectedMenuLink = this.selectedMenuLink;
        this.selectedLoanType=null;
        return searchLoans();
    }
    else if (this.getSelectedMenuLink().longValue() == 4L) {
        this.prevSelectedMenuLink = this.selectedMenuLink;
        return otherOpportunities();
    }
    else if (this.getSelectedMenuLink().longValue() == 5L) {
        //The link needs to be 'activated' once a service provider is selected.  
        this.prevSelectedMenuLink= this.selectedMenuLink;
        return this.navigateToHome();   
    }

    return null;
}
```

I added the actionlistener to check if the controller was getting fired or not, and it is.

What is happening is the following: The page loads, and before it is completely done loading if the user  clicks the button that calls this remoteCommand then strangely the actionListener gets called, but the action method does not.

Any ideas what I could do to alleviate this issue?

Thank you
Karthik

Comment: Can you also provide the code of your managed bean? And which PrimeFaces version are you using?

Comment: Thank you Lars. I added the action method to the question above. Also, we are using primefaces 3.5.8.2